# Função executando sem click do botão Python

Tags: python

Boa noite, 
Minha função callbackInsereCritico executa direto sem o click do botão,oque pode ser?

```
def callbackInsereCritico(nome):
  conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost',
                        database='diet+',
                        user='postgres',
                        password='teste')

  cur = conn.cursor()
  curCritics = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO critico (nome) VALUES ('" + nome + "')")                              
  conn.commit() 



rotuloAv = Label(formulario, text = "Cadastro do Avaliador")
rotuloNm = Label(formulario, text = "Nome:")
texto9 = Entry(formulario)
botaoAv =  Button(formulario, text = "Cadastrar",command = callbackInsereCritico(texto9.get())) 
resultadoAv = Label(formulario, text = None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não ta passando uma função da forma que você está fazendo.
Ao invés, você está executando a função `callbackInsereCritico` e passando o valor de retorno para o atributo `command`. Por isso que ela ta sendo executada sem o evento de click.

Imagine que você tem essa função:

```
def fazalgo():
    return "fizalgo"
```

Se você executar:

`type(fazalgo)`

O retorno vai ser:

`<type 'function'>`

Agora, se executar:

`type(fazalgo())`

O retorno vai ser:

`<type 'str'>`

Percebeu a diferença? No primeiro caso, a função `type` recebeu como parâmetro uma função, já no segundo, recebeu o retorno da função.

Agora, como você precisa passar um argumento para a função, você não pode simplesmente fazer: `command = callbackInsereCritico`.

Tem uma forma pythonica de fazer isso:

`command = lambda: callbackInsereCritico(texto9.get())`

`lambda` em Python nada mais é que um forma mais elegante de declarar funções. São muito úteis para certos momentos, como esse.

Então, seu código fica:

```
def callbackInsereCritico(nome):
  conn = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost',
                        database='diet+',
                        user='postgres',
                        password='teste')

  cur = conn.cursor()
  curCritics = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute("INSERT INTO critico (nome) VALUES ('" + nome + "')")                              
  conn.commit() 



rotuloAv = Label(formulario, text = "Cadastro do Avaliador")
rotuloNm = Label(formulario, text = "Nome:")
texto9 = Entry(formulario)
botaoAv =  Button(formulario, text = "Cadastrar", command = lambda: callbackInsereCritico(texto9.get()))
resultadoAv = Label(formulario, text = None)
```

Como explicar lambda aqui foge do escopo da pergunta, deixo aqui esse link:
http://blog.alienretro.com/entendendo-python-lambda/

Comment: Olá, grato pela resposta!Acredito que entendi a funcionalidade do lambda, porém se eu deixo assim como você postou, ele simplesmente não executa a função

Comment: Tem certeza? Debugou? Algum erro ou comportamento estranho?

Comment: Deu certinho, não executava por um erro de sintaxe em outra parte do código. Portanto usando o lambda, resolveu o problema! Muito obrigado fera!